# Why has the number of rejected edits been going up for me lately?

Tags: discussion, edits, suggested-edits, rejected-edits

Mostly I edit posts to correct grammar or make the title clearer (example: changing a declarative sentence into an interrogative sentence) so that more people will understand the question, upvote the question, or try to answer the question.

Lately however, a large portion of my edit suggestions have been rejected and I'm not sure why.

Is it because I am suggesting a lot of edits and thus they are reviewed more in order to make sure they're not spam?

Comment: There have been a few discussions on rejected edits lately, with the reiteration that editing solely for grammar doesn't usually improve a post that much.

Comment: @TheWanderer I disagree, I think that a post with good grammar that is easy to understand is a hell of a lot more useful than a post with poor grammar.

Comment: if the point is still clearly delivered then editing for grammar, at least when your edits need to be reviewed, isn't that helpful. Anyway, it doesn't matter so much what you think, but rather what those who are reviewing your edits think. I was giving you a possible reason.

Comment: Less significant edits will be far easier to do when you reach 2k reputation and your edits no longer need to be reviewed. Until that time do keep in mind that every edit you suggests creates additional workload for other people, so it's best to stick to really fixing problems. There usually is something that can use fixing; the title, the tags, whatever. You shouldn't often have to scramble for an excuse to fix language mistakes.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

I don't really think so, you got one suggested edit rejected by Community ♦, with a reason of:

> This edit conflicted with a subsequent edit

Second one is too little of an edit, just with a little change of "to" to "can I",

And it was rejected by a reason of:

> This edit does not make the post even a little bit easier to read, easier to find, more accurate or more accessible. Changes are either completely superfluous or actively harm readability.

And you had many others with:

> This edit does not make the post even a little bit easier to read, easier to find, more accurate or more accessible. Changes are either completely superfluous or actively harm readability.

It seems that you really like replacing "to" to "can I", which is not really making any difference, you may well should make your suggested edits better.